# Reason for eval_config setting parameters to 1 in ptb_word_lm.py

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, language-model

While examining the setting for evaluation in Tensorflow's PTB language model, I am perplexed by this setting for the evaluation in eval_config:

```
  eval_config = get_config()
  eval_config.batch_size = 1
  eval_config.num_steps = 1
```

in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

To the best of my understanding, during evaluation, a window (which could be upto num_steps size) of context words is used to predict the next word, which is stored in a separate target tensor. If num_steps is set to 1, wouldn't it imply that only the preceding word is used for prediction (ignoring a context window size>1) ? Also during evaluation, why is batch_size set to 1 as well. Wouldn't it make sense to have a larger batch being fed into the network, to speech up evaluation ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the batch size should be set to one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the unrolling for one step only in the output is to evaluate each word as it is first seen. This might also be why the batch size is 1.